# Displays a balloon message from the inno setup installer

Tags: inno-setup

Is it possible to display a pop-up **balloon** message on the taskbar during the inno setup installer?

I know it can be done through PowerShell, but I'm looking for a way to do it with an API function or a COM object and etc.